# TypeError (class or module required for rescue clause)

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.1

I've been using Stripe for over a year now, based on Ryan Bates's RailsCast episode found [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/288-billing-with-stripe?autoplay=true). However, my error handling has recently stopped working, and I've never seen this error before. I recently began running my app on Ruby 2.1, and as near as I can tell, that's the problem.

This is an instance method in my `Subscription` model:

```
    begin
      save_with_stripe_payment
    rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
      logger.error "Stripe error while creating customer: #{e.message}"
      logger.error e.backtrace.join("\n")
      errors.add :base, "There was a problem with your card."
      false
    rescue e
      logger.error e.message
      logger.error e.backtrace.join("\n")
      errors.add :base, e.message
      false
    end
```

The line:

```
    rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
```

is the one throwing the error. The stacktrace from there goes to the "begin" line, and that's it. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The line number in the error is a little misleading, the error is actually coming from this:

```
rescue e
```

I think you meant

```
rescue => e
```

Comment: Dead on, thanks Max. I used to rescue Exception and then was advised against it. Looks like I removed too much!

Answer (score 5):

I got this error because I was trying to rescue an array of exceptions, e.g.

```
rescue *exceptions => e
```

except that `exceptions` was an instance of an exception (my mistake).